# How to correctly manipulate a CV_16SC3 Mat in a CUDA Kernel

Tags: opencv, cuda

I am writing a CUDA Program while working with OpenCV. I have an empty Mat of a given size (e.g. 1000x800) which I explicitly converted to GPUMat with dataytpe CV_16SC3. It is desired to manipulate the Image in this format in the CUDA Kernel. However trying to manipulate the Mat does not seem to work correctly.

I am calling my CUDA kernel as follows:

```
    my_kernel <<< gridDim, blockDim >>>( (unsigned short*)img.data, img.cols, img.rows, img.step);
```

and my sample kernel looks like this

```
__global__ void my_kernel( unsigned short* img, int width, int height, int img_step)
{
    int x, y, pixel;
    y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if (y >= height)
        return;
    
    if (x >= width)
        return;

    pixel = (y * (img_step)) + (3 * x);
    
    img[pixel] = 255; //I know 255 is basically an uchar, this is just part of my test
    img[pixel+1] = 255
    img[pixel+2] = 255;

}
```

I am expecting this small kernel sample to write al pixels to white. However, after downloading the Mat again from the GPU and visualizing it with *imshow*, not all the pixels are white and some weird black lines are present, which makes me believe that somehow I am writing to invalid memory addresses.

My guess is the following. The OpenCV documentation states that cv::mat::data returns an uchar pointer. However, my Mat has a data type "16U" (short unsigned to my knowledge). That is why in the kernel launch I am casting the pointer to (unsigned short*). But apparently that is incorrect.

**How should I correctly proceed to be able to read and write the Mat data as short in my kernel?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the input image type should be `short` instead of `unsigned short` because the type of Mat is `16SC3` ( rather than `16UC3` ).

Now, since the image step is in bytes and the data type is `short`, the pixel index ( or address ) should be calculated taken into account the difference in byte width of those. There are 2 ways to fix this issue.

## Method 1:

```
__global__ void my_kernel( short* img, int width, int height, int img_step)
{
    int x, y, pixel;
    y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    
    if (y >= height)
        return;
    
    if (x >= width)
        return;

    //Reinterpret the input pointer as char* to allow jump in bytes instead of short
    char* imgBytes = reinterpret_cast<char*>(img);
    
    //Calculate row start address using the newly created pointer
    char* rowStartBytes = imgBytes + (y * img_step); // Jump in byte
    
    //Reinterpret the row start address back to required data type.
    short* rowStartShort = reinterpret_cast<short*>(rowStartBytes);
    
    short* pixelAddress = rowStartShort + ( 3 * x ); // Jump in short
    
    //Modify the image values
    pixelAddress[0] = 255; 
    pixelAddress[1] = 255;
    pixelAddress[2] = 255;

}
```

## Method 2:

Divide the input image step by the size of required data type (`short`). It may be done when passing the step as a kernel argument.

```
my_kernel<<<grid,block>>>( img, width, height, img_step/sizeof(short));
```

I have used method 2 for quite a long time. It is a shortcut method, but later on when I got to look at the source code of certain image processing libraries, I realized that actually Method 1 is more portable, since the size of type can vary across different platforms.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Method 2 worked for me. I will have in mind the portability issue you mentioned.